# what is wrong in this static factory method code

Tags: java, object, static-factory

*I am trying to learn static factory methods and their advantages over constructors
but my code is throwing an error that final String name is not assigned a value(name might no be initialized)*

```
public class Main {
public final String name;
private final String email;
private final String country;

public Main(String name, String email, String country) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.country = country;
}

public Main() {}

static Main createName(String name, String email) {
    return new Main(name, email, "Argentina");
}
public   static void main(String[] args) {
    Main obj = new Main();
    createName("vipin", "vipin.com");
    System.out.println("This is name: " + obj.name + "\n" + "This is email address: " + 
    obj.email + "\n" + "This is country: " + obj.country);

}
```

}

Comment: Look at this line: `Main obj = new Main();` Can you see why this would cause the error you are asking about?

Comment: On a side note, why does `createName()` return a `Main` object? Should it be `createMain()` instead? Or should the class be called `class Name`?

Comment: createName function returns main object to initialize the instance variables, in this example assigning country as a default value through createName method (i.e static factory method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Main obj = new Main();
createName("vipin", "vipin.com");
```

to:

```
Main obj = createName("vipin", "vipin.com");
```

and forget the no-parameter constructor which do not initialise correctly the fields.

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable is initialized by its default value unless it is `final` when the object is instantiated. If you initialize it out of one of its constructors, it cannot be initialized in the constructor(s). So, advisedly, `final` instance variables should be initialized in constructors.